# Logging websocket connections in Squid

Tags: networking, proxy, logging, squid, websocket

I'm monitoring Squid access.log, expecting to see when an application opens some websocket connections. But new records *seem to* appear only when the connections are closed (although I'm not 100% sure about that).

Is it expected behavior for Squid? If yes, then maybe there's a way to log connections when they are opened, or I should better use something like Wireshark for that?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I wanted to ask where you got squid from an what it's running on? What's your setup, are you speeding up your local internet?

Comment: @Cris I'm running sameersbn/squid:3.5.27-2 Docker container for development purposes, the productive setup is based on Zscaler.